# Mysql SELECT for table joined even with fileds outside the join

Tags: mysql, select

I have your MySql tables: "orders", "products" and "ingredients". In "orders" I have a field where the ingredients are inserted as a string "1,2,3 ...". In the "ingredients" table I have the primary field id and another with the name of the ingredient. As the following:

[image]

What is the SELECT to get the following result if the WHERE is orders.id=4:

[image]

insteed of:

[image]

Comment: Don't post as image.  Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The SELECT for what you want, they way you have the data currently, is overly complicated, and most likely I'll performing; you are much better off fixing your data structure so that you are not packing multiple Id values into a single row's field.

Comment: Also learn proper database design.  `order` table is a recipe for disaster.  Things that are suppose to be very easy will become complicated because of messed up table structure.